# SSMS - Is there a way to highlight changes since last save?

Tags: ssms

An example:

- If I was to have some code such as, `SELECT * FROM Table1`, and I then saved the script.
- I then changed it to:

  - `SELECT * FROM Table2`
  - `SELECT * FROM View1`
  - `SELECT Column1 FROM Table1`
- Then is there a way to highlight, within SSMS, the parts of the script that have changed since I last saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to highlight parts of the script itself from what I can tell.

The closest thing that is already in SSMS is:

> - Tools
> - Options...
> - Environment
>
>   - Font and Colors
>
>     - Display Items:
>
>       - Track Changes after save
>       - Track Changes before save

This vertical bar on the left hand side of the script page already exists. I've just changed the colors to make it more visible so I can make better use of it.

Not what I was looking for, but it will suffice.